# Issue with Dockerizing a Java Web Application and Including a Knowledge Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I am facing an issue while Dockerizing my Java web application that includes a knowledge repository. The knowledge repository is stored in the knowledge-repo folder at the root directory of my project. The application runs successfully locally, but when I deploy it using Docker, I encounter a java.io.FileNotFoundException for the file knowledge-repo/config/regex_template.yaml.

Here is relevant part of application.yaml

```
knowledge-repo:
  path: knowledge-repo
```

And here's a snippet of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:jdk21
COPY "knowledge-repo" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec/knowledge-repo
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp
COPY ./warfile/*.war .
RUN jar -xf *.war
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp/ 
 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp
COPY ./dist /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
```

Despite including the knowledge-repo folder in the Docker image, the application is unable to find the knowledge-repo/config/regex_template.yaml file, resulting in a java.io.FileNotFoundException.(I assume that this is where the knowledge-repository should be.

I have tried 3 locations for copying knowledge repo so far,but with no luck

```
COPY "knowledge-repo" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec/knowledge-repo
COPY "knowledge-repo" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/knowledge-repo
COPY "knowledge-repo" /knowledge-repo
```

Comment: By definition, your `RUN mv` should fail because the `COPY knowledge-repo"`  command created the directory above

Comment: As it turned out, it was, and I created a demo and found that the `temp` directory had not been renamed.  Maybe you should modify your `workdir` directory and modify your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by

```
FROM tomcat:jdk21
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp
COPY ./warfile/*.war .
RUN jar -xf *.war
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec
COPY ./knowledge-repo /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec/knowledge-repo
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/temp
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec/*.war
COPY ./dist /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spec
```